# Keyframe simple maya loops in python?

Tags: python, maya

I have this very simple python script in Maya that I want to animate.
I first want to adapt the end time of the animation to the number of iterations, in order to have enough keyframes for the animation.
After that I want to add a keyframe for the movement of the polyCube at each loop iteration to produce the moving animation.

```
import maya.cmds as mc

iterations = 10 #number of keyframes
transVal = 1 #translation value for each iteration

mc.polyCube(constructionHistory=True, width=1, height=1, depth=1)

for i in range(iterations):
    mc.move(transVal, cube, relative=True, moveZ=True)
    mc.setKeyframe(insert=True, value=i)
```

Would it alternatively be possible to add a keyframe at the beginning and one at the end and let maya calculate the motion tweens (like it does in the UI)?

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripting in Maya is the same thing as using the GUI so yes its possible to do exactly the same thing as in GUI.

```
import maya.cmds as mc

distance = 10
timedelta = 10

cube = mc.polyCube(constructionHistory=True, width=1, height=1, depth=1)
mc.setKeyframe(cube[0], time=1, v=0, at='translateZ')
mc.setKeyframe(cube[0], time=timedelta, v=10, at='translateZ')
```

Comment: what if i want to add another key frame to the same cube after 50 frames to move 10 units on y axis?